# Doubt regarding "Negation of a proposition"

Tags: discrete-mathematics, propositional-calculus

Consider the proposition,

> Vandana's smartphone has at least 32 GB of memory.

Three valid negations are,

> It is not the case that Vandana's smartphone has atleast 32GB of memory.
>
> Vandana's smartphone does not have atleast 32GB of memory.
>
> Vandana's smartphone has less than 32GB of memory.

I am wondering if I put it like this,

> Vandana's smartphone has 2GB of memory.

Is that still a valid negation to the above proposition ? I am wondering,any value less than 32GB could possibly negate that poroposition ?
(I arbitrarily used the value '2')

(This example is taken from Section 1.1 of Discrete Mathematics and Apllications by Kenneth H Rosen)

Comment: I do not think so... The negation of the prop $p$ is not-$p$ (2nd negation above). In natural language this is usually expressed with : "it is not the case that $p$" (1st negation above). In the case of the predicate "has at least" the cumbersone expression "it does not have at least" can be streamlined with "it has less than" (3rd negation above).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The negation of $x\geq 32$ is not going to be $x=2$.   You will want to make a claim that will be true for *any* viable value of $x$ that makes $x\geq 32$ false, not just a particular example.

Comment: Thank you,that was helpful :) .I delved too much into the 'natural language' part of the proposition.